# A problem about the convergence of convolution

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a topological group. Let $f_{n}$ and $g_{n}$ be two sequences in $L^{p}(G)$ that are convergent to $f$ and $g$, respectively. Let $f * g \in L^{p}$. Is $f_{n} * g_{n}$ convergent to $f * g$? why? 
($f_{n}*g_{n}\in L^{p}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$).

Comment: What does \ast mean ?

Comment: it's LateX for *

Comment: It's the convolution

Comment: Do you assume that $f_n * g_n$ is also in $L^p$?

Comment: Yes,$f_{n}*g_{n}$ is in $L^{p}$ for each natural n

Comment: In general, convolution does not map $L^p\times L^p$ to $L^p$. It will however map $L^p\times L^p$ to $L^{\frac{p}{2-p}}$.

Comment: I think Young's inequality works here (but it has been a while...)